# Can't get Heroku & Nginx to redirect http requests -> http

Tags: nginx, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm using the `heroku/nodejs` and `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nginx.git` buildpacks.

I've created the `/app/congig/nginx.conf.rb` file required and I see this in build log, `

I see this in my `heroku logs` output: `Starting process with command 'bin/start-nginx npm run start'`

So I know nginx is running.  But I also see `Server: Cowboy` in the response headers when I make requests to the app. So I have no idea why my config would be TOTALLY bypassing NGINX and serving up from Cowboy instead??

Here's my nginx.conf.rb:

```js
daemon off;
#Heroku dynos have at least 4 cores.
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

events {
 use epoll;
 accept_mutex on;
 worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  gzip on;
  gzip_comp_level 2;
  gzip_min_length 512;

 server_tokens off;

 log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
 access_log logs/nginx/access.log l2met;
 #error_log logs/nginx/error.log debug;
 error_log stderr info;

 include mime.types;
 default_type application/octet-stream;
 sendfile on;

 #Must read the body in 5 seconds.
 client_body_timeout 5;

 upstream app_server {
  server unix:/tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout=0;
  }

 server {
  listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
  server_name _;

  keepalive_timeout 5;

    root   /app/build;

  location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
   if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
      }

   proxy_pass app_server;
  }
 }
}
```

Furthermore.. I haven't a CLUE as to where the error.log and access.log files are!  I've even tried setting those to `/var/log/access|error.log` and nope.. they aren't there on the server when I look using `heroku run -a app-name bash`!

So lost as to how to get this working...  Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the nginx "buildpack" requires you to touch a file in `/tmp` before it'll bother starting up nginx...

So adding `fs.closeSync(fs.openSync('/tmp/app-initialized', 'w'))` to my Node app allowed nginx to start up and handle the redirect.

Comment: Hey Raven, I have kinda similar issue ( but its intermittent ) and details of my question is posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977433/facing-intermittent-404-issue-when-calling-rails-api ... Maybe you can be of help