# Facing intermittent 404 issue when calling Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, heroku, thin, cowboy

I have banged my head on this for 2 days now and i dint find any luck yet. Looking for help on this.

**The issue:**

Front End makes 10 similar XHR requests ( for different users ) to my Rails API and few of the requests randomly fails with 404 status code.

**My Observations:**

- If i make the same request again, It passes.
- I dont see any trace of 404 requests even hitting my server ( using logs ).

  - I do see different response headers for 200 and 404 ( mentioned below ) and i see `cowboy` ( https://github.com/heroku/cowboyku, https://github.com/heroku/vegur) `server` for 404 requests. I run my rails production with `thin` web server.

My theory is that, As few of my requests are not able to hit my `thin` server, they are getting 404. Now, the confusion is, Why is it hitting `cowboy`

**200 Status Code**[image: **200 Status Code**]

**404 Status Code**[image: **404 Status Code**]

**[EDITS]**
response payload for 404 errors is something like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>No such app</title>
        <style media="screen">
          html,body,iframe {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
          html,body {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
          }
          iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 0;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <iframe src="//www.herokucdn.com/error-pages/no-such-app.html"></iframe>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "Front End makes 10 similar XHR requests ( for different users )" -- how similar? If they're for different users is it possible that it's a user record not being found? (I'm assuming not if exactly the same request succeeds subsequently.) Also, roughly what percentage of requests fail?

Comment: They are for different users and users do exist. An immediate call to the same 404 endpoint will give you 200.

Out of 10, 1-3 calls fail on general

Comment: So is this a Heroku issue? How many dynos is your app using? Is it possible that somehow some of the requests are hitting a proxy that isn't configured properly? Have you tried rebooting your dyno(s)?

Comment: I used to have 1 dyno before. For troubleshooting i have increased it to 3. I have rebooted multiple times by now. No luck

Comment: And also sometimes all the requests get 200 also. So its very intermittent.